# SSRS 2008 - How to Total values from an expression

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to figure out how to total values from a calculated field.

In the example below, I have the following expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!Role.Value = "Contractor", Fields!actualwork.Value * 100,
Fields!actualwork.Value * 77)
```

Now I want to provide a total, but it doesn't show up on the report. Is there something I'm missing?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFFkN.jpg]

Answer (score 10):

You actually just put a SUM around the outside:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Role.Value = "Contractor", Fields!actualwork.Value * 100,
Fields!actualwork.Value * 77))
```

It will evaluate that row by row and will provide the correct sum.

Answer (score 2):

Try casting it to type double, like this:

```
=SUM(CDbl(Fields!YourField_f.Value))
```